# LyX-typed document exported to plain LaTex?

Tags: lyx

LyX is nice for fast homeworks and fast prototyping but not for quality type-setting at least for now as a beginner so how can I export LyX-typed document to plain LaTeX to work on the document elsewhere such as Emacs and TextMate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File --> Export --> LaTeX (pdflatex).

Comment: My goal is to get the LaTeX code, not the PDF document.

Comment: @hhh You didn't try that did you. It produces a `.tex` file in the same folder as the `.lyx` file.

Comment: No LaTeX (pdflatex) option in my LyX: http://i.stack.imgur.com/R4IaJ.png

Comment: @hhh Look under *More Formats and options* then.

Comment: Nothing there as well: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YOywd.png. I clicked other options and I got *.tex file produced, thank you -- no idea yet why I am missing pdflatex, ideas?

Comment: @hhh I really don't know why it's not there. The LuaTeX and  XeTeX options will also give you LaTeX code, though it might be aimed at those engines in some respects.

Comment: @hhh My guess is that LaTeX (pdflatex) is not there because you are using features that are specific to XeTeX and LuaTeX. Do you happen to have the box checked in Document > Settings > Fonts that says "Use non-TeX fonts (via XeTeX/LuaTeX)" ?

Comment: @scottkosty thank you! You are correct. LuaTex was clicked long-time ago that I had totally forgotten, shame on me. Thank you for clarifying :)